# Displaying tags in Rails outputs literal html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a simple blog Rails app and am trying to output links to tags here: `Tags: <%= tag_links(@article.tags) %><br />`. Rails seems to be generating the correct html, but it shows up in the browser as `Tags: <a href="/tags/1">ruby</a>, <a href="/tags/2">tutorial</a>` (literally).

I checked the source html, and it shows this: `Tags: &lt;a href="/tags/1"&gt;ruby&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href="/tags/2"&gt;tutorial&lt;/a&gt;`, which seems to be converted to the correct tags, but is displayed literally as text instead of converted to HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "html_safe" method like:

```
<%= tag_links(@article.tags).html_safe %>
```

OR use "raw" like:

```
<%= raw tag_links(@article.tags) %>
```

You should put those in your own method (tag_links) at the return values. Eg.,

```
def tags_links
  html = ""

  html << link_to "some_where", some_url

  html.html_safe
end
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<%= raw tag_links(@article.tags) %>
```

instead of

```
<%= tag_links(@article.tags) %>
```

The `raw` method will bypass the automatic HTML escaping.